# Show that for all symmetric matrices there exists a matrix A that satisfies a given equation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

[image]

Hi,

So I am not sure how to solve this problem. I have two ideas, the first is:

$$ AQ + QA^{t} = M $$
$$ AQ + (QA^{t})^{t} = M $$
$$ AQ + AQ = M $$
$$ 2AQ = M $$
$$ A = (1/2) M*Q^{-1} $$

But I am not sure if Line 2 is correct or allowed.

Or, I had the idea of showing that

$$ AQ + QA^{t} =  (AQ + QA^{t})^{t}  $$
$$ AQ + QA^{t} =  AQ + QA^{t}  $$

Thus, we know that the transformation is a symmetric matrix. 
But that does not seem rigorous or thorough to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Line 2 isn't correct. $\Phi$ is linear. So use what you know about linear maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 2, there is no guarantee that changing the expression to its transpose will give the same matrix $M$.

So, I would take the transpose of the LHS.

$$(AQ+AQ^t)^t=M^t=M=AQ+AQ^t$$
$$Q^tA^t+(Q^t)^tA^t=QA^t+QA^t=AQ+QA^t$$
$$QA^t=AQ$$

And then you can make the argument that you made after line 2.

Comment: I think when you transpose the formula you should get AQ+ QA_t + , not AQ + AQ_t @Andy